# Hibernate relationship confusion with uni and bidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, entity-relationship

I have Spring Data JPA experience, but new for Hibernate and after looking at several tutorials and  articles, now I am too confused with some points. Could you please clarify me about the following issues?

**1.** Regarding to OneToMany relationship, it is suggested to define this relationship in the table e.g. `Country` table instead of the related table e.g. `Employee` table with `country_id` map key. However, there are different kind of implementations for this and other relationships.

What does Uni or Bidirectional relationship mean in Hibernate?

Could you please give an example or suggest me a good example (except from documentation that also cunfused me) in order to understand all the relationships used in Hibernate?

**2.** For the ManyToMany relationship, some example use `List<T>` while some others use `Set<T>`, `Collection<T>`. So, what is the proper way to define multiple relationship entity?

**3.** There are also some unnecessary implementation e.g. `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` or `@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")` because these are default implementation. So, as far as I see, there is no need to imply these default settings as they have no impact. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options because there are many different use cases.

1. Choosing between Bidirectional and uni has an impact on the Java Object mapping the entities, how the association is mapped on the database and which query Hibernate will use to load entities (or convert HQL queries). I'm not going into the details of everything - [the documentation does already a great job at it](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations) - but if we take the following bidirectional association:

   ```
   @Entity(name = "Person")
   @Table(name="PERSON_TABLE")
   class Person {

     @Id    
     private Long id;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
     private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

   }

   @Entity
   @Table(name="PHONE_TABLE")
   class Phone {

     @Id    
     private Long id;

     @ManyToOne
     private Person person;

   }
   ```

   Hibernate will map it adding a column `person_id` on the table `PHONE_TABLE`.

   If instead we map it as a unidirectional one-to-many:

   ```
   @Entity(name = "Person")
   @Table(name="PERSON_TABLE")
   class Person {

     @Id    
     private Long id;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
     private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

   }

   @Entity
   @Table(name="PHONE_TABLE")
   class Phone {

     @Id    
     private Long id;

     // No many-to-one in this class

   }
   ```

   Hibernate creates an extra table `Person_Phone` (a bridge between `PHONE_TABLE` and `PERSON_TABLE`), that contains two columns `person_id` and `phone_id`.
2. It depends what type of content you expect the association to contain and how you want it returned: does it have duplicates? Is it ordered? Do you want the result as they appear on the db or do you want to use a comparable on the collection? Which mapping are you using? List is usually a good generic option, but you might have better performances using another implementation in some cases, like when you many-to-many associations or when you want to load multiple associations eagerly.
   This question on stack overflow explains why [one cannot load multiple lists eagerly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334831/multiplebagfetchexception-thrown-by-hibernate) and the documentation [list all the available collections](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-entity) ([there are many more  articles on-line](https://thorben-janssen.com/association-mappings-bag-list-set/#Don8217t_use_a_List_for_many-to-many_associations)). Here's an excerpt from the docs:

   > unidirectional bags are not as efficient when it comes to modifying the collection structure (removing or reshuffling elements).
   >
   > Because the parent-side cannot uniquely identify each individual child, Hibernate deletes all link table rows associated with the parent entity and re-adds the remaining ones that are found in the current collection state.
3. `@JoinColumn` is optional, and it's usually necessary when users want to change some of the defaults. For example, when you want to change the column name mapping the association:

   ```
   @Entity
   class Book {

      // Default column name would be `author_id` but we change it to `a_id`,
      // if you are fine with author_id, than `@JoinColumn` is not necessary
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
      Author author;
   }
   ```

   In regard to `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`, Hibernate cannot always fetch many-to-one associations lazily. So the default is `EAGER`. When Hibernate load an association lazily, it creates a proxy object of the expected class. The problem is that you could have code like this:

   ```
   Book book = session.find(Book.class, 5);
   if ( book.getAuthor() == null ) {
    // do something ...
   }
   ```

   If Hibernate creates a proxy every time, `getAuthor()` will never return null. So if hibernate can guess that the author exists without querying the associated table, it will load it lazily (for example, when one specifies that the association always exists), otherwise it will just query the associated table and create the object eagerly.

Comment: Thank you so much for these wonderful explanations. Voted up ;) Regarding to your answers, could you clarify me about these points?

Comment: **1.** Regarding to bidirectional and unidirectional one-to-many, is the key difference `@ManyToOne private Person person;` in the `Phone` entity? Or do `id` fields have also impact for that? I am wondering if there would be any difference if we also use `id` fields for `Phone` and `Person` entities in the first scenario (bidirectional association)?

Comment: **2.** Thanks for explanations and useful links.

Comment: **3.** Then, I think it would be a good practice to use `@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")` even if not required for default column name so that I will need to use a different name. On the other hand, could you give a good convention example for the usage of OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToMany in the documentation or an article?

Comment: **1**. Ah sorry, entities must have an id. I've just omitted it because it doesn't matter too much what type you use.

Comment: **3** I don't usually add annotations unless I have to. But you can choose whatever approach you prefer. The Hibernate docs contain example for each mapping, I'm not going to copy and paste it here to answer your question. Please, don't ask people to do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Regarding to #3, I mean that point the proper part on the documentation or an example article that shows related relationships. because there are similar parts that I can mix by mistake.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations

Comment: Yeah, I was exactly looking for that sections and completely understand the difference between uni and bidirectional relations. The only think that I don't like with bidirectional relations is `addPhone` and `removePhone` methods. I think we always have to define them for bidirectional relations. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, you need to update both sides every time. You can avoid that if you enable Bytecode enhancements: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-dirty-tracking-bidirectional

Comment: SO is not the right place for this kind of conversations. Check the Hibernate forum (https://discourse.hibernate.org/) or zulip (https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user). I think I've answered your initial question and more. Good luck.

Comment: Regarding to my **2nd** question, I have just read the [documentation part](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-mapping-associations) and confused. Regarding to **Bidirectional associations**, should we use `List` or `Set` with `Bidirectional associations`? Any clarification pls?

Comment: It depends on the requirements. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72655802/hibernate-relationship-confusion-with-uni-and-bidirectional/72656846#72656846

Comment: What about `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods? Do we always override them in the entities or should we omit or override via `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)` in the entities if we do not need any special behaviour?